# Playing video with qt 5.2 on imx53 with gstreamer and HW accelerator

Tags: qt, video, gstreamer

i tried to run qt qml video example from qt 5.2 on imx53 board with gstreamer support.
Our system modules:ltib/imx53/x11/qt5.2
i encountered the following issues when doing that:

1 – When i play video with: gst-lunch palybin2 “file” , the results are ok. The playbin2 finds and uses the relevant plugins for the gstreamer with the vpu.

2 – When i run the video example from Qt 5.2 , i see that the performance is very poor, and it can play Only mp4 format.

3 – i saw that the lib qt5multimedia do not use the Freescale plugin/element mfw_v4lsink plugin -> poor performance.

4 – i also check this patch for qt 4: Freescale patch: “Qt phonon gstreamer back end for imx53” https://community.freescale.com/thread/277496. didn’t find similar patch for qt 5.

5 – When i tried to patch the Qt5 multimedia lib to force work with mfw_v4lsink it ends up with good performance but with full screen view “outside the Qt application world”. of course it’s not good solution.

Did any one success  to run the qt 5 video example with the freescale HW accelerator?
10x for any help.